# Reference request: Local Euler characteristic

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, galois-representations

I'm learning p-adic Galois representation, here is the background:

Let $K$ be a p-adic field, and $G_K$ is the absolute Galois group of $K$. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional p-adic representation of $G_K$. I want to learn the local Euler characteristic about representations. That's something like
$$\chi(V)=dim_{\mathbb Q_p}H^0_{cont}(G_K,V)-dim_{\mathbb Q_p} H^1_{cont}(G_K,V)+dim _{\mathbb Q_p}H^2_{cont}(G_K,V)$$
Which may have properties like $\chi(V)$ only depends on the dimension of $V$.

Could you provide some references?

Comment: The statement for $\mathbf{Q}_p$-vector space representations is usually deduced from the statement for finite modules of $p$-power order, which (largely for historical reasons) is much better known, it even has a Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Euler_characteristic_formula.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler How does one go from finite modules of p power order to Qp vector spaces?

Comment: There's a standard technique: from finite p-torsion modules, taking inverse limits gets you to fg free $\mathbb{Z}_p$-modules ("devissage"), and then inverting p gets you to $\mathbb{Q}_p$-vector spaces. This is carefully worked out in one of the appendices to Rubin's orange book on Euler systems (and no doubt in many other places too).